# javafx application name on gnome

Tags: java, linux, javafx, gnome

I help to develop an application with JavaFX for linux and OSX. On Linux, we cannot have the application name on the gnome top bar. We have the entry point for JavaFX. The window have the good name but on gnome we have something like "com.myApp.javaFXMainClass".

I have the same problem with swing and I was able to correct it with these code :

```
// Set name in system menubar for Gnome (and Linux)
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("linux")) {
    try {
        Toolkit xToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Field awtAppClassNameField = xToolkit.getClass().getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
        awtAppClassNameField.setAccessible(true);
        awtAppClassNameField.set(xToolkit, "MyApp"); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

How to do that with JavaFX ?

Comment: found any solution ?

Comment: I found this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8097949 it seems fixed on OpenJFX

Comment: No, it is not "fixed" in a way that makes it useful to us as developers.  See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 9):

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Preloader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestPre extends Preloader {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().setName("app test");
    }   
}


package test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.Base64;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Test __app = new Test();
                Stage __stage = new Stage();
                __app.start(__stage);
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        String __simage = "iVBORw0K.....";
        ByteArrayInputStream __imgstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(__simage));
        javafx.scene.image.Image __image = new javafx.scene.image.Image(__imgstream);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(__image);       

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Test.class, TestPre.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add more text to explain the answer ?

Comment: Despite the lack of explanation. This actually works perfectly. Within an class extending javafx.application.Preloader you can set the application name. But you can't do that in the Application class as it is too late.

Comment: worked perfect in my case. instead of Application.launch(Test.class, args), using         com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Test.class, TestPre.class, args) and that solved my issue. thanks a lot @Eugene Smirnov

Answer (score 1):

This bug has already been reported [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8097949) but I couldn't get it working so mt final resort was to create an `awt` application as a bootstrap to `JavaFx` and it's working like charm

- Read about Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications [Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)

Code snippet [@gitlab](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1726871)

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class CustomJavaFxAppName {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("CustomJavaFxAppName");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }
        };
        initJFXPanel(jfxPanel);
        f.add(jfxPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void initJFXPanel(JFXPanel jfxPanel) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            javafx.scene.control.Label label = new javafx.scene.control.Label(
                System.getProperty("os.name") + " v"
                + System.getProperty("os.version") + "; Java v"
                + System.getProperty("java.version"));
            StackPane root = new StackPane(label);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
        });

        if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("linux")) {
            try {
                Toolkit xToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                Field awtAppClassNameField = xToolkit.getClass().getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
                awtAppClassNameField.setAccessible(true);
                awtAppClassNameField.set(xToolkit, "MyApp");
            } catch (Exception ignored) { }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new CustomJavaFxAppName()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, not exactly what I was hopping but that may help

Comment: please if you got a better solution, then share it with us. I'm eager to see more progress with this one

Comment: I have come up with a workaround/solution.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround/solution which should be relatively easy to use for anyone packaging their JavaFX application in a jar using some sort of build-tool (e.g. Maven, Gradle, Leiningen) which supports Maven dependency style coordinates:

- One small class dropped into your project
- Two small dependencies
- Two values in your manifest
- One additional arg to your java startup command
- One environment variable in your startup-script

See/get the source here: [no.andante.george.Agent](https://bitbucket.org/andante-george/george-application/src/default/src/java/no/andante/george/Agent.java)

(Detailed usage/help embedded in the source.)

Hope it is useful.
*(Do let me know if you were able to use it successfully in a comment bellow.)*

---

**Understanding the problem and this solution**

*The problem is a double whammy!*

Digging into the OpenJDK source you will find in 'sun.awt.X11.XToolkit' (which extends 'sun.awt.UnixToolkit' which extends 'sun.awt.SunToolkit' which extends 'java.awt.Toolkit'):

```java
    private static String awtAppClassName = null;
```

If you set this variable to whatever you want (with introspection) early enough (e.g. at the beginning of your `main` method), your value will get picked up and passed on to the underlying GTK system when the Toolkit windowing system is initialized.  This is what e.g. [IntelliJ](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) does in [com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/22932021087050c6ec5417d9bd93b620819118b3/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ui/AppUIUtil.java#L184)

However, digging into the OpenJFX source you will find in 'com.sun.class.ui.Application':

```java
    private final static String DEFAULT_NAME = "java";
    protected String name = DEFAULT_NAME;
```

Looking at this, your first idea might be to do
`com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setApplicationName(..)` .
But that won't work because it is too late!  The `name` variable was set at class instantiation and then passed on to the underlying GTK system before your code got called.

So then you try to use introspection to set the constant `DEFAULT_NAME` to what you want, and so that will get used to instantiate the variable `name`.  But that also doesn't work! Why?

Because of the keyword `final` (which is the most significant difference between the Toolkit and the Application implementation)!
Because it is final static and is assigned the value `"java"`, the value is "inlined" at compile time.  I.e. it is inserted into the "constant pool", and all references to the constant `DEFAULT_NAME` are replaced with a reference to the constant pool.  And so, even if you set the constant at runtime, it will be ignored, and any code (in this case the constructor) will simply set the variable `name` to the value which was compiled into the constant pool.

I don't think you can alter the constant pool or the body of the constructor with introspection.  If you can, I would like to know how!

*Enter ASM*

But if you can rewrite the actual byte-code of the class before it gets loaded by the JVM, then you can do pretty much anything!

So I chose to write a small "Java Agent" (think of it as JVM middleware). All it does is look for the environment variable 'APPLICATION_NAME', and if found it will look for the class 'com.sun.glass.ui.Application' and transform it slightly before it is passed on to the JVM and the class loader:

First, it sets the constant `DEFAULT_NAME` to the value of 'APPLICATION_NAME'.  Then, it alters the body of the Application constructor such that the variable `name` is assigned the value of `DEFAULT_NAME` (instead of the value in the constant pool). Finally, it disables the method `setName` (by removing its body).

Hope this is interesting and possibly useful to someone.  Please do see (and use) my solution linked at the top of this answer.  Feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Interresting search but unusable for most applications :(

Comment: Yes, you are right @Tutul.  I have updated the initial part to clarify the scope and applicability of this answer/solution.